# Count all occurrences of a char within a string

Tags: scala

Does Scala have a native way to count all occurrences of a character in a string?

If so, how do I do it?

If not, do I need to use Java? If so, how do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: If you needed a count for every character in a string, this related question might prove useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105130/generating-a-frequency-map-for-a-string-in-scala

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
"hello".count(_ == 'l') // returns 2
```

Comment: Nothing special needs importing. I've tried it with 2.8.2 and 2.9.1, both work as expected for me.

Comment: @santiagobasulto: it shows the beauty of functional programming not just Scala; giving all the praise to Scala would be unfair to the many functional languages that have existed for decades.

Comment: @isea: You might have made the same mistake that just happened to me. Check to use single quotes not double quotes for the char to count! :)

Answer (score 3):

i don't use Scala or even java but google search for "Scala string" brought me to [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html)

which contains :

```
def
count (p: (Char) ⇒ Boolean): Int
Counts the number of elements in the string which satisfy a predicate.
p
the predicate used to test elements.
returns
the number of elements satisfying the predicate p.
Definition Classes
TraversableOnce → GenTraversableOnce
```

Seems pretty straight forward but i dont use Scala so don't know the syntax of calling a member function.  May be more overhead than needed this way because it looks like it can search for a sequence of characters. read on a different result page a string can be changed into a sequence of characters and you can probably easily loop through them and increase a counter.

Comment: worrying about overhead and proposing a more efficient solution is really premature optimization at its best :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a higher level approach to look into substring occurrences within another string, by using `sliding`:

```
def countSubstring(str: String, sub: String): Int =
  str.sliding(sub.length).count(_ == sub)
```