# Generating a frequency map for a string in Scala

Tags: string, scala, dictionary

Let's say I have a string, "hello", and I want to generate a character frequency map:

```
Map[Char,Int] = Map(h -> 1, e -> 1, o -> 1, l -> 2)
```

I could do this iteratively:

```
val str = "hello"
var counts = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Char,Int]
for (i <- str) {
    if (counts.contains(i))
        counts.put(i, counts(i) + 1)
    else
        counts.put(i, 1)
}
```

By messing around in the REPL, I've found I can do something a bit more concise and not using a mutable collection:

```
> str.groupBy(_.toChar).map{ p => (p._1, p._2.length)}
scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(h -> 1, e -> 1, o -> 1, l -> 2)
```

But I don't know about the performance characteristics of groupBy() nor what is going on in the block passed to map (like what, exactly, p is).

How do I do this idiomatically using the functional paradigms in Scala?

---

For background, I'm just coming to Scala for the first time from Ruby. In Ruby, I would use `inject` but I'm not sure what the parallel way to do it in Scala is:

```
counts = str.each_byte.inject(Hash.new(0)){ |h, c| h[c] += 1; h}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### 1) What does `p` mean?

`groupBy` takes a function which maps an elements to a key of type `K`. When invoked on some collection `Coll`, it returns a `Map[K, Coll]` which contains mappings from keys `K` to all the elements which mapped to the same key.

So, in your case, `str.groupBy(_.toChar)` yields a map mapping from a key `k` (which is a character) to a string with all the elements (characters) `c` such that `k == c.toChar`.
You get this:

```
Map(e -> "e", h -> "h", l -> "ll", o -> "o")
```

A `Map` is an iterable of pairs of keys and values. In this case, each pair is a character and a string of elements. Calling the `map` operation on a `Map` involves mapping on these pairs - `p` is a pair where `p._1` is a character, and `p._2` is the associated string (on which you can call `length`, as you did above).

### 2) How to do this idiomatically

The above is how to do it idiomatically - using `groupBy` and `map`. Alternatively, you can use an immutable map and recursion on the string length to compute the frequencies, or an immutable map and a `foldLeft`.

### 3) Performance characteristic

Best to [benchmark](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/performance.html) to see the differences.
Here are a couple of microbenchmark for a highly-repetitive string (~3GHz iMac, JDK7, Scala 2.10.0 nightly):

```
object Imperative extends testing.Benchmark {
  val str = "abc" * 750000

  def run() {
    var counts = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Char,Int]
    var i = 0
    val until = str.length
    while (i < until) {
      var c = str(i)
      if (counts.contains(c))
        counts.put(c, counts(c) + 1)
      else
        counts.put(c, 1)
      i += 1
    }

    //println(f)
  }
}


object Combinators extends testing.Benchmark {
  val str = "abc" * 750000

  def run() {
    val f = str.groupBy(_.toChar).map(p => (p._1, p._2.length))
  }
}


object Fold extends testing.Benchmark {
  val str = "abc" * 750000

  def run() {
    val f = str.foldLeft(Map[Char, Int]() withDefaultValue 0){(h, c) => h.updated(c, h(c)+1)}
  }
}
```

Results:

- Imperative: `$    103 57  53  58  53  53  53  53  53  53`
- Combinators: `$   72  51  63  56  53  52  52  54  53  53`
- Fold: `$  163 62  71  62  57  57  57  58  57  57`

Note that changing the imperative version to use `withDefaultValue`:

```
var counts = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Char,Int].withDefaultValue(0)
var i = 0
val until = str.length
while (i < until) {
  var c = str(i)
  counts.put(c, counts(c) + 1)
  i += 1
}
```

is apparently terribly slow due to forwarding each `put` call:

- `withDefaultValue`: `$    133 87  109 106 101 100 101 100 101 101`

Conclusion: the boxing and unboxing of characters in this case is high-enough so that the differences in performance between these approaches are hard to observe.

EDIT:

Update: You may want to use [ScalaMeter inline benchmarking](https://scalameter.github.io/home/gettingstarted/0.7/inline/) in place of the `Benchmark` trait.

Answer (score 26):

Extending Axel's answer.

Your `groupBy` solution is already functional. There's just a tiny-tiny correction to it which could make it cleaner:

```
str.groupBy(_.toChar).mapValues(_.size)
```

The Scala's alternative to `inject` is `foldLeft`, `foldRight`, `reduce`, `reduceOption` depending on how you use it. The way you've used `inject` in Ruby is not functional, since your solution is based on mutating `h` and in functional world mutability is a "no-no". Here's how you'd do the solution close to your `inject` but in functional style in Scala:

```
str.foldLeft( Map[Char, Int]() ){ (m, c) => m + (c -> (m.getOrElse(c, 0) + 1)) }
```

Obviously `groupBy` looks much better.

Comment: I think you can just do `groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)` because a String is already treated as a sequence of chars; there's no need to convert with `toChar`

Answer (score 11):

Your example on ruby can be almost directly translated to Scala using `foldLeft` and immutable `Map`.

Here is one of possible solutions:

```
str.foldLeft(Map[Char, Int]() withDefaultValue 0){(h, c) => h.updated(c, h(c)+1)}
```

Actually, if you are ok with local mutability, you can make something like this:

```
def charFrequencies(str: String): collection.Map[Char, Int] = {
  val hash = collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[Char, Int] withDefaultValue 0
  str foreach { hash(_) += 1 }
  hash
}
```

Expression `hash(_) += 1` will be desugared to `c => hash(c) = hash(c) + 1` and then to `c => hash.update(c, hash.apply(c) + 1)`

This solution should be more efficient than functional ones, because it don't create intermediate collections. Also because method returns immutable `collection.Map[Char, Int]`, result will be treated as immutable (as long as no one will perform unsafe downcasting on it).

Comment: You could also return a map that really is immutable with `hash.toMap`

Answer (score 6):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, we can use the [`groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/WrappedString.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) method which is (as its name suggests) an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` and a reduce step:

```
"hello".groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
// immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(e -> 1, h -> 1, l -> 2, o -> 1)
```

This:

- `group`s characters (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s each grouped value occurrence to 1 (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values within a group of values (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).

This is an equivalent version [performed in one pass](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) through the sequence of chars of:

```
"hello".groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.map(_ => 1).reduce(_+_))
```