# groupBy on String in Scala

Tags: scala

I am doing a groupBy on a string as follows:
`"message".groupBy("message".count(_.toChar))`
I was expecting it to yield a map as:
`{1 => "mag" , 2 => "es"}`
However the above code doesn't even compile , where am I going wrong. I want to produce a map based on the discriminator function count of chars.

Comment: why is this expected?

Comment: because as per my limited understanding (new to Scala) , groupBy would first receive "m" , then "e" and so on one by one , and it would count the occurrence of each character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
("message".groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
 .groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.foldLeft("")(_+_._1)))

// res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(2 -> es, 1 -> amg)
```

Comment: I read a similar solution that makes sense , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105130/generating-a-frequency-map-for-a-string-in-scala , but whats not clear to me is why would my solution above not work.

Comment: `String.count` expects a boolean value, for your method, you could try `"message".groupBy(c => "message".count(_ == c))`.