# Scala string.count('\t'==) Why does it work?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a string s, if I want to count the amount of tabs in the string I can do the following:

```
string.count('\t'==)
```

Any idea why this works?? I would've expected a predicate

Reference: [Count all occurrences of a char within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908930/count-all-occurrences-of-a-char-within-a-string)

Comment: `'\t'==` is a (somewhat unreadable) equivalent of `ch => '\t' == ch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` is being used as a "postfix operator", so you are effectively passing in the function `'\t'.==` to `string.count`.

Note: if I do this in the REPL with `-feature` turned on, I get this output:

```
scala> "hello\tworld".count('\t'==)
<console>:8: warning: postfix operator == should be enabled
by making the implicit value language.postfixOps visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.postfixOps'
or by setting the compiler option -language:postfixOps.
See the Scala docs for value scala.language.postfixOps for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
              "hello\tworld".count('\t'==)
                                       ^
> res0: Int = 1
```

Adding the dot removes the warning:

```
scala> "hello\tworld".count('\t'.==)
res1: Int = 1
```

Comment: But try typing `'\t'.==` into the REPL. You say you're passing a function, but there is overloading and eta-expansion in the mix. The expected type is crucial. Now I have to upvote b/c upvoted the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is your question

- Does String have a function `count(p: (Char) ⇒ Boolean): Int`?
- Is the `==` method on a char a boolean function on another char?

The answers: yes and yes.

Comment: What a great answer, but I see why they call you `Malvolio`.

Answer (score 1):

In scala you can pass predicate this way:

```
def predicate(ch: Char) = { ... }

string.count(ch => predicate(ch))
```

or this way

```
string.count(predicate(_))
```

Also there is way to omit parameter placeholder, which looks actually nice

```
string.count(predicate)
```

And in your example you are actually calling method '==' of Char, so it's very similar to code above. Just far more unreadable.

```
string.count('\t'.==)
```